# Model project dependencies in Gradle: Add a dependent project to another project

Tags: project, gradle, build-dependencies

I am facing the following problem. I have two Gradle projects (ProjectA and ProjectB) on the same hierarchy without any root project. Since ProjectA depends on ProjectB, I tried to model this as follows:

ProjectA's **settings.gradle**:

```
includeFlat 'ProjectB'
```

ProjectA's **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjectB')
}
```

However, then I am getting the following error when executing 'gradle build' on ProjectA:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ProjectA'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Module version group:, module:ProjectA, version:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, configuration:compile declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ProjectA, module:ProjectB, version:unspecified
```

Do I have to define some kind of default configuration in ProjectB?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have do defined some kind of default configuration in ProjectB?

Either that, or apply the `base` plugin. Many other plugins (`java`, `groovy`, `scala`, etc.) apply the `base` plugin automatically, so that you don't have to.

Comment: I already have applied the plugin 'Java' to both ProjectA and ProjectB. Also adding 'base' produces the same error. It seems that I am missing some fundamentally stuff here. :)

Comment: Which directory are you executing the build from? Multi-project builds with a non-hierarchical directory layout have to be executed from the directory containing `settings.gradle`, unless that directory is called `master`, or `-p` is used to point to that directory.

Comment: I was executing 'gradle build' from the directory of ProjectA. I got it running now with introducing another parent directory (which acutally does nothing), and defining their a 'gradle.build' and the 'settings.build' including both subprojects. That worked. However, it would have been nicer if I would not have to add this level of hierarchy.

Comment: There is no known good way to implement automatic discovery of `settings.gradle` for non-hierarchical builds. Searching all sibling directories for each build invocation is prohibitive performance-wise.